# Copied Embed returning empty

Tags: discord, discord.js

So basically, I am trying to fetch embed from 1 channel and then send it to another channel but it's giving an error saying something about empty message.

Full Error:

```
Received 1 messages
/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:171:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/874619472902774845/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Here is my bot script:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });;

client.on('ready', () => {
const channel1 = client.channels.cache.get("791100523246911499");
const logchannel1 = client.channels.cache.get("874619472902774845");


channel1.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
    console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`);
    //Iterate through the messages here with the variable "messages".
    messages.forEach(message => {
        logchannel1.send(message.embeds);
    })
  })
```

I hope someone knowledgeable in discord.js can help me out with this dilemma.

Thanks for reading
Regards, Infamous.

Answer (score 0):

This part is incorrect

```js
messages.forEach(message => {
        logchannel1.send(message.embeds);
    })
```

You have to specify they are embeds

```js
messages.forEach(message => {
        logchannel1.send('optional content', {embeds: [...message.embeds]});
    })
```

Comment: How would i do if i wanted to pass message.embeds in a discord webhook

Comment: Exactly the same way, but instead of 'optional content', remove it, and replace it with `{content: 'optional content', embeds: [...message.embeds]}`

Comment: I tried it, hook1.send({embeds: [...message.embeds]}); it's giving me a error. (node:19416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at /home/stealer/node_modules/webhook-discord/lib/webhook.js:296:38
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Webhook.send (/home/stealer/node_modules/webhook-discord/lib/webhook.js:294:16)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/stealer/index.js:46:15)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)

Comment: I also tried doing: webhookClient.send({ content: 'Logs', username: 'Logs', embeds: [message.embeds], }) Which gives me error 405 method not allowed